# Make my navigator change size with the browser

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm having an issue with my navigator showed when the user is on a mobile device. I want the navigator to scale up with the browser and I have been trying a lot of things out.. seems that nothing works.

**Here's my HTML.**

```
<ul class="mobilemenu">
                    <li><a href="http://workbyjimmi.se/construction.html">ABOUT ME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://workbyjimmi.se/construction.html">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://workbyjimmi.se/construction.html">PROJECTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://workbyjimmi.se/construction.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
```

**And here's my CSS.**

```
.mobilemenu
{
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
    filter: dropshadow(color=#000, offx=0, offy=0);

}

.mobilemenu li
{
    display: block;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-top: 2%;
    width: 40%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(135,6,29,0.8);
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}
```

You can also go check my page and scale it down 'til you see the other navigator.

***www.workbyjimmi.se***

Comment: what do you mean by "scale up". As it is defined in percent it should scale but I think I don't understand what you are trying to acheive. Maybe add one or two screenshots or sketches (desktop/mobile)?

Comment: I would suggest you to add `background-size:cover` to your `body` styles.

Comment: I'm using media-queries to detect when to show to mobile-version of my navigator. But I want it to stay the same size even when im on 320px width or 380px for example. Go check my website and scale it down: www.workbyjimmi.se

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use media queries. You can find more out about them here: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

*I might be miss-understanding what you are trying to do. But even if my example is wrong, you can use media queries to help target different devices. You can make media queries to target specific screen sizes to make the required differences you need in your navigation. There is a tone of information in google if you want to learn more about it.

I've also made this from your code, try resizing the preview window to see how the menu changes. http://jsfiddle.net/2mDxa/3/

HTML

```
<ul class="mobilemenu">
    <li><a href="http://workbyjimmi.se/construction.html">ABOUT ME</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://workbyjimmi.se/construction.html">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://workbyjimmi.se/construction.html">PROJECTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://workbyjimmi.se/construction.html">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
body{ margin: 0; }
.group:before,
.group:after,
.mobilemenu:before,
.mobilemenu:after{
    content: "";
    display: table;
} 
.group:after, .mobilemenu:after {
    clear: both;
}
.group, .mobilemenu {
    zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}
.mobilemenu
{
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
    filter: dropshadow(color=#000, offx=0, offy=0);
}

.mobilemenu li{
    display: block;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(135,6,29,0.8);
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}  

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
 .mobilemenu li{
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    }       
}
```

After your comments, do you mean scale like this?: http://jsfiddle.net/2mDxa/4/

Comment: I'm already using media-queries, but I want to make the nav stay in the middle and enlarge with the the browser.

Check my website and try scale it down: http://workbyjimmi.se/

Comment: Please check the link at the bottom of my answer, is that what you mean by scale with the window?

Comment: Thank you, this is how I want it. The only problem now is that in the mobile device - the background won't scale down so the menu isn't in the right place anyways.. any clue about this?